# How can I configure a service-specific firewall on Linux?

Tags: linux

How could I configure some kind of firewall which only allows specific programs to use the open ports in the system (preferably RHEL)?

For example, if I want `yum` to be able to connect and update normally, but I want to block outbound web requests like browsing, I would still need ports 80, 443, 53 and UDP-53 to be open.

However, I'd need the firewall to be able to distinguish between `yum` and web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables` has the ability to check the program's user.

Using `--uid-owner` or `--gid-owner` flags you have the ability to limit network to specified users only (root?), and your webserver (may run as `www-data`) packets would be dropped.

Of-course this limits per user/group and not per program, but most services today run with their own users and groups.

Example:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner www-data -jDROP
```

Example that would restrict outbound networking to anyone except root:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -jALLOW
```

Another approach would be to setup rules with `SELinux` (usually bundled with RedHat products). I personally think that it would be harder to manage.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's much clearer to me now. It is not an approach I would have thought about. Can it stack? How many users can be specified? I'm trying to find a way so that it can scale better.

Comment: @schroeder Well, if you have multiple programs that require the same rule, they can be added to a group instead of creating a rule per user.